# nginx regexp and openresty

Tags: nginx, openresty

My nginx should match these requests:

- /id/**12345**
- /id/**12345**/**qualifier**

and */qualifier* should be optional.

i want to use in a small lua openresty script the two matched groups (12345, qualifier) with ngx.var[]

i am trying with this location, but is not working for me.
how i can say that **/** and **qualifier** are optional?

```
location ~ ^/id/(\d+)(/?)(\w+?)$ {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^/id/(\d+)(?:/(\w+))?$`

(?:) is a non-capturing group.